# Knockout: how to catch the event where you clear the textbox by clicking on the x?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using autocomplete to populate a textbox in a grid. The add new Line button is enabled if the line is entered, otherwise it is disabled. The valueUpdate property does not appear to capture the event where the user click on the x in the textbox to clear it. How do I fix this?

```
           <td style="width: 380px">
                <input type="text"
                       data-bind="enable: enableContractIfConditionsNotMet, 
                       css: { redBorder: validLine() === false }, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown',
                       jqAuto: {
                            source: getOptions,
                            value: SelectedContract,
                            labelProp: 'Label',
                            inputProp: JobDescription
                            }"
                       style="width: 99%; text-transform: uppercase;" />
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <button data-bind="click: addLine, enable: isFull()">Create New Line</button>
            </td>
```

The isFull method is computed variable that needs to be run when the Job Description field changes.

Comment: Can you make an example snippet or fiddle? I don't get an x in the textbox at all. I also don't get any updating of the computed at all.

Comment: It will take me while to do that and if I find the time I will. But to find the x, hover your mouse over a texbox with content and you should see an x near the right edge. When you click on it, the content disappears. I think this is a HTML5 feature.

Comment: Sorry not HTML5, it is IE10+